# Text-anchor not working if window is smaller than 1024 pixels

Tags: jquery, html

Why isn't my jump-to-top text-anchor "^ nach oben" working, if the window is smaller than 1024 pixels? See: https://bong-apotheke.de/

Even trying to add the functionality with a small jquery snippet doesn't work:

```
    $("a#jump-to-top").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, "slow");
        return false;
    });
```

What's the problem? Do I miss something? Tried it in Chrome but it's the same in Firefox. First I thought, a jquery-script might be the problem, but it's the same without...

Hope one of you has an idea...

Comment: Hi! *"See: https://bong-apotheke.de/"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code and examples) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's because of the CSS `@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px)
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}` remove it

Comment: Thanks T.J. for your hint. I will consider it with my next question. And thanks caramba for the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in sidebars.css

In line 24 you set height of the body to be 100%. When you disable this, the scroll will work.

Comment: Thanks that's the solution! This css comes from a slidebar-libary (https://www.adchsm.com/slidebars/) and setting the body to height:auto solves the problem. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because your page isn't long enough. Most browsers only allow you to scroll to the point where the bottom of the page is at the bottom of the viewport, and no further.

A couple of options:

1. Add a visual indication on the target of the scroll so the user's eye is drawn to it even though it's not at the top of the page.
2. Add a blank element to the end of the page that's as tall as the viewport, so that the browser allows you to scroll down to that target.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the page is long so this couldn't be the problem. The answer of Hans Dash below was the solution...

Comment: @Christian - I'm glad he found the answer for you. Please update the question so it meets SO's standards. The information Hans Dash used to figure that out isn't in the question. [As I said yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930418/text-anchor-not-working-if-window-is-smaller-than-1024-pixels/50930497?noredirect=1#comment88859832_50930418), it must be.

Comment: I understand, but the code is so long so how should I know, in which part the problem is? Still don't know what would be the correct SO-way to ask my question correctly. I'll talk to a collegue later who knows SO much better and longer than me... Thanks.

Comment: @Christian - The correct way is described in the link I provided: [mcve] Happy coding!